# c# - How to detect what line text is on in a richTextBox

Tags: c#

So I want to know what line specific text is on. Eg:

```
if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("hello!") || 
    richTextBox1.Text /* is on the second line */ ){
  // do things
}
```

Comment: You want to know on which line is present the word "hello"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RichTextBox has some functionality built in for this task....

```
int pos = rtb.Find("Hi", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
if(pos != -1)
{
    int line = rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(pos);
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

[RichTextBox.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Searches for text within the contents of the RichTextBox.

There are many overload of Find, someone allows you also to create a loop to find all matches specifying a start index for the search.

[RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Retrieves the line number from the specified character position within
>   the text of the RichTextBox control.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
// First, split your text as lines:
var lines = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// Then, check just the second line (since in your example you are only interested in the second line):
if(lines.Length > 1)
{
    if(lines[1].Contains("hello!")
    {
        // do things
    }
}
```